# Load HTML in CKEditor

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

Could someone explain to me how to load HTML into the CKEditor?

I have an editor in an asp.net page using the ajaxtoolkit. I have a AsyncFileUpload control that allows the user to upload an HTML file which I read and assign the value to the editor's Value property (which appears to be the way to load data into the control). However, this doesn't load the HTML ?!?

I've tried several different methods, but they all come down to this more or less...

```
editorCorps.Value = Server.HtmlEncode(html)
```

or simply

```
editorCorps.Value = html
```

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: Could you show some more code? I would suggest just a pure JS `setData(html)` and populating the html with asp.net.